# Certificate File 'Note.UWP_TemporaryKey.pfx' not found

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to develop a mobile app by xamarin forms in visual studio 2017. I named my project 'Note' and then named it again 'Notes'.So I changed all 'Note' to 'Notes'.When building my project that gives a warning, Certificate File 'Note.UWP_TemporaryKey.pfx' not found. Please help me!

Comment: open the UWP Csproj with editor and change the name of the UWP_TemporaryKey.pfx file

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the your namespace and right click and then select "**Rename**" and enter your new namespace and press "**Apply**" on the dialog box.